# expectation of a ratio vs ratio of the expectations

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, ratio

Consider a stochastic vector $\mathbf{x}(t)$, that I know is ergodic and stationnary.

Are they conditions on the distribution of $\mathbf{x}(t)$, that allow me to approximate $E\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}(t)}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}(t)}\right)\approx$ $\frac{E(\mathbf{x}(t))}{\mathbf{1}^TE(\mathbf{x}(t))}$ ?
where $\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}(t)$ is the sum of the elements of $\mathbf{x}(t)$.

The full question, is one of population ecology: I consider some i.i.d. environmnents (say 3), reprenseted by projection matrices $\mathbf{M}_1$,$\mathbf{M}_2$ and $\mathbf{M}_3$ which occur with probabilities $p_1$,$p_2$ and $p_3$ (that sum to 1) and an initial population as vector   $\mathbf{n}(0)$.
$\mathbf{n}(t+1)=\mathbf{M}(t)\mathbf{n}(t)$, with $\mathbf{M}(t)$ having the above distribution.

$\mathbf{n}(t)$ is therefore stochastic as is the vector of relative abundances $\mathbf{w}(t)=\frac{\mathbf{n}(t)}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{n}(t)}$

I know that $E(\mathbf{n}(t))=\mathbf{M}^t \mathbf{n}(0)$ with $\mathbf{M}=\sum p_i \mathbf{M}_i$ and i wish to understand how to obtain $E(\mathbf{w}(t))$.
So far, I have $\mathbf{w}(t+1)=\frac{\mathbf{n}(t+1)}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{n}(t+1)}=\frac{\mathbf{M}(t)\mathbf{n}(t)}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{M}(t)\mathbf{n}(t)}=\frac{\mathbf{M}(t)\mathbf{w}(t)}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{M}(t)\mathbf{w}(t)}$

$E(\mathbf{w}(t+1))=E_{\mathbf{M(t)}}[E(\mathbf{w}(t+1)|\mathbf{M}(t)=\mathbf{M})] $ and this is where I am blocked.

But if I can write $E(\mathbf{w}(t+1)|\mathbf{M}(t)=\mathbf{M})=E(\frac{\mathbf{M}\mathbf{w}(t)}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{w}(t)})\approx\frac{\mathbf{M}E(\mathbf{w}(t))}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{M}E(\mathbf{w}(t))} $ , then I can go on and I get
$E(\mathbf{w}(t+1))\approx\sum_i p_i \frac{\mathbf{M}_iE(\mathbf{w}(t))}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{M}_iE(\mathbf{w}(t))}$ and then equaling $E(\mathbf{w}(t+1))$ and $E(\mathbf{w}(t))$ this provides an equation in $E(\mathbf{w}(t))$ that I can solve.
I did a few simulations ant it seems to be not too far off, by chance maybe?

Clearly I cannot apply this approximation to $\mathbf{n}(t)$ itself as it would give $E\mathbf{w}(t)=\mathbf{w}$ with the latter being the right eigenvector associated with the dominant eigenvalue of $\mathbf{M}$, which is not what we have: the expectation of $\mathbf{w}(t)$ as t tends toward infinity is not equal to $\mathbf{w}$. But  $\mathbf{n}(t)$ is not stationnary.

Any help would be much much appreciated !

Comment: If everything is just linear, can you just normalize the matrices $M_1,M_2,M_3$ so that the sum is a constant? I.e. instead of $m_{i,j} $, use $m_{i,j}/(\sum_ i m_{i,j})$. If you do that, the denominator is just a constant of 1 and you can just study the relative population dynamics evolution.

Comment: Interesting question. You might play with the definition of the expectation and see if you can derive an approximation in terms of first and second moments only by Taylor expanding the denominator: $\langle \sum_i x_i \hat{e}_i/\sum_i x_i \rangle = \int \frac{\sum_i x_i \hat{e}_i}{\sum_i x_i } P(\{x_j\}) \prod_i  dx_i  $. If you ask me right off, is $\int \frac{\sum_i x_i \hat{e}_i}{\sum_i x_i } P(\{x_j\}) \prod_i  dx_i   \approx \frac{\int \sum_i x_i \hat{e}_i P(\{x_j\}) \prod_i  dx_i }{\int \sum_i x_i  \prod_i  dx_i }$, I'd say probably not

Comment: @Eric:  do you mean: normalise each (column) vector of the matrix $\mathbf{M}_1$ for instance ? but then it will have a completely different behavior than the original $\mathbf{M}_1$, so I can't draw conclusions from it, can I ?

Comment: Yeah, wait, never mind, I was being silly. That just doesn’t work. I’m not sure of a good approach. I like the Taylor Series approximation method.

Comment: @kevinkayaks: thanks for that! I will try that and keep you posted